# NETSUITE SAVED SEARCH (SALES ORDER QTY) & (ITEM FULFILLMENT QTY)

Tags: transactions, formula, netsuite, saved-searches

I have issue showing in saved search the accurate quantity of sales order and item fulfillment accurate quantity in one line based on the SO document number , because its showing wrong quantities

saved search tried a lot of formulas